# Why does .onclick affect all anchor link with the same URL?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some html on test.html and JavaScript code on test.js. I put alerts in the functions to test it, and I'm constantly getting only the first alert (1232c) regardless of which hyperlink I click on. I don't understand, I have a reference to a specific anchor element using its id, why does .onclick think they are all the same if they have the same URL (form.html). I want only function test to happen if I click the hyperlink with id 1232c, and function test2 to happen if I click the hyperlink with id1232b.

```js
function init () {
  var jobID = document.getElementById("1232c");
  var jobID2 = document.getElementById("1233b");
  jobID.onclick = test("1232c");
  jobID2.onclick = test("1233b");
}

function test(id) {
  alert(id);
}

function test2(id) {
  alert(id);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<a href="form.html" id="1232c">Apply</a>
<a href="form.html" id="1233b">Apply</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

An event listener requires a function to be assigned to it. Currently you're assigning the result of *calling* those functions. Note: you don't need two functions to deal with the clicks. Since you're passing in an id as an argument just use `test` to cater for both events.

##### Option 1

Assign a function to the listener that calls `test` when the event is fired.

```
jobID2.onclick = () => test('1233b');
```

##### Option 1

Assign `test` directly to the listener, and log/alert the id from the clicked anchor.

```js
var jobID = document.getElementById("1232c");
var jobID2 = document.getElementById("1233b");

jobID.onclick = test;
jobID2.onclick = test;

function test(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<a href="form.html" id="1232c">Apply</a>
<a href="form.html" id="1233b">Apply</a>
```

There are a couple of alternative approaches.

##### Approach 1

1. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to grab all the anchors.
2. Iterate over the anchors and assign event listeners to them.
3. The handler accepts an event `e`. It first prevents the anchor from its default action (going to the page indicated by the href), and then logs the id of the element that was clicked.

```js
// Cache the anchors
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Iterate over the anchors and add a listener to
// each one
anchors.forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});

// The handler accepts the event as an argument,
// prevents the redirect, and then logs the clicked
// anchor's id
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<a href="form.html" id="1232c">Apply</a>
<a href="form.html" id="1233b">Apply</a>
```

##### Approach 2

Use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Add one listener to a containing element (a `section` perhaps as in this example), and assign it a handler that deals with all the click events from its child elements.

1. Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab the container.
2. Add one event listeners to the container.
3. The handler accepts an event `e`. It first checks to see what element was clicked. If it's an anchor it prevents the anchor from its default action, and then logs the id of [the anchor that was clicked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

```js
// Cache the container
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

// Add a listener to the container
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// The handler accepts the event as an argument,
// prevents the redirect, and then logs the clicked
// anchor's id
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('a')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <a href="form.html" id="1232c">Apply</a>
  <a href="form.html" id="1233b">Apply</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function before clicking

You have to assign a function, not a function call

```js
function init() {

  var jobID = document.getElementById("1232c");
  var jobID2 = document.getElementById("1233b");
  jobID.onclick = () => test("1232c");
  jobID2.onclick = () => test("1233b");

}

function test(id) {
  alert(id);
}

function test2(id) {
  alert(id);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<a href="form.html" id="1232c">Apply</a>
<a href="form.html" id="1233b">Apply</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in that `jobID2` calls `test()` and not `test2()`. As you describe it, that may be all you need.

But, if you are trying to wire up on click handlers, you need to assign *functions* to the onclick property. What you have assigned is the return values after you call `test()` during window OnLoad. Something like this:

```
jobID.onclick = test;
```

or as @Konrad described, an anonymous function if you need to pass in that argument:

```
jobID.onclick = () => {
    test("1232c");
};
```

(I don't believe the order of the function definitions is important due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting))